# Missing File in Download stack

Tags: macos, data-transfer

I have a file that shows up in my 'Downloads' stack with the filename nMEMp5Qv.exe.part.

However, when I open Finder, the file is not in the Downloads folder.

Also, I can't delete the file from the Stack as you normally can...?

Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Is it shown by `ls -a ~/Downloads/`? Have you already tried logging out and back in? A similar issue where deleted files are shown on the desktop is fixed by just reopening Finder.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 . Delete the stack from your dock and drag the download folder again into the dock and try

Download stack ? Check you download history -

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV* 'select LSQuarantineDataURLString from LSQuarantineEvent'
```